# Как добавить часть HTML кода (на сервере) в index.html?

Tags: html, node.js

Как добавить часть HTML кода, что хранится в переменной cardsData в index.html?

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

//БД
const url = 'https://reqres.in/api/users';

//инициализация глобального окружения
global.document = new JSDOM(this.html).window.document;
global.window = new JSDOM(this.html).window;

var cardsData;


async function getCards() {
    await fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
        cardsData = json.data.map(el => {
            return `
                <div class="col col--hidden" >
                    <div class="card">
                        <img src="${el.avatar}" class="card-img-top"  width="200" height="200" alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">${el.first_name} ${el.last_name}</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">${el.email}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            `;
        });
    });
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('index.html'));
    getCards();
});

server.listen(3000, (err) =>{
    if(err){
        throw Error(err);
    }
    console.log('Server is runnig');
});
```

index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Business Cards</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">Business Cards</span>
        </div>
    </nav>
    
    <div class="card-group justify-content-center">
        <div id="cards" class="row row-cols-2 row-cols-md-3"></div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="loadMore" class="loadMore"> Load More </a>

    <footer>
        <div class="text-center p-4" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);">
            © Nimchenko Anastasiya 2021
        </div>
    </footer>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $(function(){
                $("#loadMore").on('click', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(".col--hidden").slice(0,3).slideDown().removeClass('col--hidden');

                    $(this).toggle();
                })})
        });
    </script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @yar85 ответил на ваш вопрос [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1307441/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4-onload#comment2308494_1307441) и ещё один подход вам рассказали [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1304815/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81-rest-api-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-html-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5#comment2303333_1304815). и на хабре. домашка?

Comment: @nörbörnën тип того. важный проект, который надо сделать именно через HTML

Comment: а как звучит постановка задачи в этом важном проекте?

Comment: @nörbörnën Create web page, that will render data from https://reqres.in/api/users. 

Use node.js and any framework (preferably express.js) to create the page
Create web service to get response from API
Create controller that will render the results on browser
Page should have “load more” button to get more cards without page reload